# Combining subranges of a vector efficiently to iterate through

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20

## Combining subranges of a vector efficiently

### The Process

I have some numerical data stored in vector, *v*. Vector *v* is composed of many subranges of valid/invalid data with unpredictable lengths according to some predicate, e.g. being above some threshold value. After filtering, these valid ranges are represented by a second vector, *f*, which contains std::pair<size_t, size_t>'s indicating the start index of the range and index one past the end of the range.

For example, filtering the vector { 1, 5, 3, 12, 10, 21, 19, 14, 5, 9, 3, 7, 2 } for data above a threshold of 10 would return { {3, 8} }

### The Data

The data I am using originates from real world measurements of the output power of a laser as it is cycled on and off. The transfer from off to on, and vice versa, is not instantaneous, and noise during the transition can make it difficult to determine the exact start point/end point.

The data produced is treated as immutable and no alterations are applied to *v*.

### The Filter

In addition to the data to be filtered and a threshold value, the filter takes a value, *x* representing the number of valid/invalid elements it should encounter before determining there has been a transition from a valid subrange to an invalid one, or vice versa.

For example, using the same vector as above, { 1, 5, 3, 12, 10, 21, 19, 14, 5, 9, 3, 7, 2 }, but a threshold of 8 and *x* = 2:

- The filter reaches index 3, recognizing 12 > 8.
- It continues *x* more indices, checking that they are also above the threshold before recognizing a transition has occurred.
- The start point is set to 3.

The reverse happens for the transition from above the threshold to below.

- The filter reaches index 8, recognizing 5 < 8.
- However, at index 9. *v*[9] = 9 > 8.
- As there haven't been *x* values below the threshold, the valid subrange continues.
- At index 10 the count starts again, this time finding a valid transition.
- The end point is set to 10 (One past the end).

## The Problem

By only retaining the information about the start and end points of the valid ranges I avoid keeping a copy of all the valid data.

At a later point, I then perform some transformation on the data such as taking the average of each range (nice and simple), or averaging the valid data into a maximum number of *n* points (which causes my problem).

#### How can I smoothly iterate through the valid indices of *v* across subranges?

My first thought was to look at the Ranges library provided by the C++ standard; however, I'm very inexperienced in using <ranges> and my simple experiments with it have probably led me further from a workable answer than I was initially through added confusion.

I am currently using Visual Studio 2022 and compiling for c++20.

Compiled using:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O3 -std=c++20 example.cpp
```

example.cpp

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <limits>

std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t>>
filter( const std::vector<double>& data,
        const double threshold,
        const size_t x ) {
    std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t>> range_indices;
    // continuous_range indicates if currently in a continuous, VALID range.
    bool continuous_range{ false };
    // range_start/end track indices of most recent valid range
    // count helps distinguish between noise & transitions
    // from invalid to valid ranges or vice versa.
    size_t range_start{ 0 }, range_end{ 0 }, count{ 0 };

    for ( size_t i{ 0 }; i < data.size(); ++i ) {
        /* Some logic to decide which switch branch
        * Possible values:
        * 0: data[i] < threshold & !continuous_range
        *      - In non-valid data range, reset count.
        * 1: data[i] >= threshold & !continuous_range
        *      - Found new valid range if count >= x, else incr count
        * 2: data[i] < threshold & continuous_range
        *      - Left a valid range if count >= x, else incr count
        * 3: data[i] >= threshold & continuous_range
        *      - Within continuous range, rest count.
        */
        size_t branch = data[i] >= threshold ? 2 : 1;
        branch += continuous_range ? 1 : -1;

        switch ( branch ) {
        case 0:
            count = 0;
            break;
        case 1:
            count++;
            continuous_range = count >= x;
            if ( continuous_range ) {
                range_start = i - count + 1;
                count = 0;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            count++;
            // If count == x, no longer in cont. range
            continuous_range = !(count >= x);
            // If not in cont. range
            if ( !continuous_range ) {
                // 1 past the end
                range_end = i - count + 1;
                range_indices.push_back(
                    std::pair<size_t, size_t>{ range_start, range_end }
                );
                count = 0;
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            count = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Handle case were valid range includes final datapoint.
    if ( continuous_range && range_start > range_end ) {
        range_indices.emplace_back(range_start, data.size() - 1);
    }

    return range_indices;
}

double
vector_max( const std::vector<double>& v ) {
    double max{ std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest() };

    for ( const auto& d : v ) {
        if ( max < d ) { max = d; }
    }

    return max;
}

double
mean( const std::vector<double>& data,
      const size_t start, const size_t end ) {
    if ( data.empty() ) {
        return std::numeric_limits<double>::signaling_NaN();
    }
    if ( start >= end || end > data.size() ) {
        return std::numeric_limits<double>::signaling_NaN();
    }

    double sum{ 0.0 };
    for ( size_t i{ start }; i < end; ++i ) {
        sum += data[i];
    }

    return sum / (end - start);
}

std::vector<double>
avg_range( const std::vector<double>& data,
           const std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t>>& valid_ranges ) {
    std::vector<double> avg_data;
    avg_data.reserve(valid_ranges.size());

    for ( const auto& [first, last] : valid_ranges ) {
        avg_data.emplace_back(mean(data, first, last));
    }

    return avg_data;
}

std::vector<double>
avg_npoints( const std::vector<double>& data,
             const std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t>>& valid_ranges,
             const size_t n ) {
    /*
    * Some method to iterate through the valid ranges in data
    * using valid_indices so they appear as one continuous range.
    * Then average the valid data into n points.
    */
}

int main() {
    /*
    * I would put data here, except in reality the code handles anywhere
    * from a few 100k to a few million datapoints so I'm not sure what to
    * provide instead.
    */
    std::vector<double> data;

    const auto indices = filter(data, 0.8 * vector_max(data), 2);

    const auto range_avgs = avg_range(data, indices);
    const auto npoint_avgs = avg_npoints(data, indices, 1000);
}
```

Comment: its not quite clear why averaging the data causes a problem. Perhaps some code that illustrates the issue would help

Comment: Building a proxy class that keeps a reference to the vector (shared_ptr?) and the vector of ranges and implements an iterator should be easy. Then you can use `for (auto & x : proxy)` and all the other iterator/range based things.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Sorry for taking a while to get back to you, I've had quite a busy weekend.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number the reason averaging the data is an issue is because I want to treat the valid data differently depending on how I'm looking at it.  In the case of reducing the data down to a user defined total number of points it no longer makes sense to treat them range-by-range. Instead, it would be more convenient if there was a way to transparently iterate through the valid ranges of the data as if they were one using only the indices of the valid ranges and the unchanged original data.

Comment: once you have the ranges you can write a function `for_all_in_range(F f)` that applies `f` to all elements in the range. Or use a `proxy` as suggested by Goswin. Its probably just 2-3 lines of code, but without code from your side its difficult/impossible to give a useful answer

Comment: Note that numeric_limits::min may not be what you think.

Comment: `views::join` (plus maybe `views::iota`) may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the ranges library offers ways to write your code in a much simpler way. However, you already have the code to filter and if we just consider the question

> How can I smoothly iterate through the valid indices of v across subranges?

Then the answer is rather simple and requires only few additions to your code.

First I used an alias

```
using indices_t = std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t>>;
```

Next, your way to find the max can be simplified by using `std::max_element`:

```
double vector_max( const std::vector<double>& v ) {
    return *std::max_element(v.begin(),v.end());
}
```

(assumes the vector is not empty)

Then you can write a function that takes a callable as parameter and calls it with all elements inside the intervals:

```
template <typename F>
void apply_to_intervals(F f,const std::vector<double>& v,const indices_t& indices) {
    for (const auto& interv : indices) {
        for (auto i = interv.first; i < interv.second; ++i){
            f(v[i]);
        }    
    }
}
```

Thats really all you need to smoothly iterate the filtered elements.

For example to print them:

```
void print(const std::vector<double>& v, const indices_t& indices) {
    apply_to_intervals([](double x) {std::cout << x << "\n";},v,indices);
}
```

To calculate the average:

```
auto avg_range(const std::vector<double>& v,const indices_t& indices) {
    double sum = 0;
    size_t count = 0;
    auto averager = [&](double x) {
        sum += x;
        ++count;
    };
    apply_to_intervals(averager,v,indices);
    return sum / count;
}
```

[Complete Code](https://godbolt.org/z/3rrornb8s)

Comment: Thanks for this, after spending quite a while staring at the documentation for <ranges> I was tending towards something similar. That said, this is a lot more elegant than what I was considering!

Comment: @BenAndrews you should make yourself familiar with the standard algorithm library. Many algorithms have a nicer counter part in the ranges library, but already using standard algorithms can help you a lot. Getting the max element is only one example I spotted in your code and my `apply_to_all` also just follows the common pattern of turning the loop inside out by passing a callable, something that you'll find in the algorithm library all over the place

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed do this quite elegantly with ranges. Here is a short example:

```
#include <ranges>
#include <span>
#include <vector>

// Store your subranges as
using Sub = std::span<double>;

// and return your filtered result as
std::vector<Sub> filter(std::vector<double> const& data, ...);

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> data;
    const auto subs = filter(data, ...);

    // A view of the vector of spans, flattened into a single sequence
    auto view = std::views::join(subs);
}
```

The spans can be created from a pair of iterators to the data vector, or an iterator and a count, so that will require some modifications to your filter algorithm.